# Arc shape not rendered smoothly

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I've created an arc at a 12 o'clock position on a CAShapeLayer and added it as a sublayer onto a UIView. The arc is rough or bumpy. I tried antialiasing, corner radius, line join, and have also tried rasterizing at one point but no luck. Any ideas why it's not smooth and what to do to make it smoother? If make the same arc at 9 or 3 o'clock they are smooth, but not 12 or 6 o'clock. Appreciate any help.

Here's the code:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 38.25, 38.25, 25, degreesToRadians(304), degreesToRadians(236), YES);
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[shapeLayer setAllowsEdgeAntialiasing:YES];
[shapeLayer setEdgeAntialiasingMask:kCALayerLeftEdge | kCALayerRightEdge | kCALayerBottomEdge | kCALayerTopEdge];
[shapeLayer setCornerRadius:2.0];
[shapeLayer setLineJoin:kCALineJoinRound];
[shapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
[shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[color CGColor]];
[shapeLayer setLineCap:kCALineCapRound];
[shapeLayer setLineWidth:3.0];
[shapeLayer setPath:path];
```

Here's a link to the arcs. Top and bottom are not smooth like on the left. They look less smooth on a device. Screen capture sort of smoothed them out more than they actually are.
http://oi57.tinypic.com/2wf4i9c.jpg

Comment: I hope you’re `CGPathRelease()`ing your path when you’re done with it!

Comment: By the way, `corerRadius` may cut in to the path. You probably don’t want to mix it with `CAShapeLayer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your layer is off the pixel bounds. That is, it’s rasterizing the layer, then shifting it by a fractional number of pixels before drawing. My first suggestion would be to round those x.25 values to whole numbers.

By the way, why are you passing `304, 236` as the `startAngle` and `endAngle` in `CGPathAddArc()`? Those parameters are in radians, not degrees.

`edgeAntialiasingMask` and `allowsEdgeAntialiasing` has to do with how the edges of the layer’s rectangular bounds are rendered, and should not affect the contents.

**Edit**: the difference is subtle, but when I stop using fractional values, the slight bumps in the line go away. By the way, if you post your images in .png format, it’s easier to see what’s going on, because they don’t get the artifacting from jpg compression.

```
// Fractional values
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 138.25, 138.25, 25, degreesToRadians(304), degreesToRadians(236), YES);
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[shapeLayer setLineJoin:kCALineJoinRound];
[shapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
[shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
[shapeLayer setLineCap:kCALineCapRound];
[shapeLayer setLineWidth:3.0];
[shapeLayer setPath:path];
CGPathRelease(path);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

// Integral values
CGMutablePathRef newPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(newPath, nil, 200, 138, 25, degreesToRadians(304), degreesToRadians(236), YES);
CAShapeLayer *newShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[newShapeLayer setLineJoin:kCALineJoinRound];
[newShapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
[newShapeLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
[newShapeLayer setLineCap:kCALineCapRound];
[newShapeLayer setLineWidth:3.0];
[newShapeLayer setPath:newPath];
CGPathRelease(newPath);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:newShapeLayer];
```

And the result:

[image: Side-by-side comparison]

When I overlay them in Difference Mode in Photoshop, you can see where the pixels differ:

[image: Comparison in Difference Mode]

Comment: Hi Zev, I'm a bit new, thanks for explaining. I made those values ints, but it's still fuzzy. The start/end is edited to be radians (I was trying to simplify things for posting and left that out accidentally). The top arc bound is {{24.020178, 13}, {27.959646, 4.2740612}} so maybe when choosing start and end angle, the containing rect for it should be integer values?

Comment: What are the bounds of the layer after you are done? Are you moving it manually at all?

Comment: Also, try changing the x and y to 38, 38 instead of 38.25, 38.25, and see what happens.

Comment: I set to 38, 38 and it's still bumpy. I tried to get the frame/bounds in viewDidAppear, but it's {{0, 0}, {0, 0}} for both. The view it is contained in has frame {{122, 308}, {76.5, 76.5}}. I also tried with width height constraints 76, 76 instead of 76.5, 76.5. The layer isn't moved manually, it's added as a sublayer onto a view that is positioned with constraints later on.

Comment: Posted my results when trying it with integral values. Does that address the artifacting you had been seeing?

Comment: I made the center point ints, tried nudging start/end angles and radius but didn't get a noticeable change here. Not sure what's going on otherwise. May be something I just have to live with. heh. Really appreciate that you helped me to understand it better.

Comment: If you would be willing to post your project, or a pared-down version of it, I could have a look.

Comment: Hey Zev, I looked at it more closely and it changes, but it's squeezed into retina so that made it harder to notice, but it's also confined to a very specific area so I couldn't nudge positioning much more or in a way that would make it match is 9 o'clock positioned counterpart. Thanks again.